# creating Dynamic properties of a relationship in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to create dynamic properties of a relationship.
Below is what I am trying to do....

```
String createRelQuery = "MATCH (a:emp),(b:mngr) WHERE a.name={1} AND b.name={2} MERGE (a)-[r:manage{{4}:{3}}]->(b)";

    try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(RelQuery)) {
            stmt.setString(1, getempName());
            stmt.setString(2, getmangrename());
            stmt.setString(4,"Name"+getempName());
            stmt.setString(3, getmngrname());
            }
```

The error I am getting is

> Error executing cypher statement(s)
>   [{code=Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax, message=Invalid input
>   '{': expected whitespace, comment, a property key name, '}', an
>   identifier or UnsignedDecimalInteger (line 1, column 115

Am I giving any invalid syntax which is causing the problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameters cannot be used for property names, see http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.1/cypher-parameters.html